# Black bars on iframe embedd

Tags: iframe

I am trying to remove black bars from my iframe video. Please help me.

Html code:

```
 <div class="tube_video">
   <iframe class="video_custom" src="video url" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
 </div>
```

and css

```
.tube_video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.tube_video iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 288px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px none;
}
```

It is showing the black bars of  both left and right side which seeing very ugly on my page. Please htlp me.